# Как в java сделать comit в sql если я хочу закомитить много объектов?

Tags: java, sql, запрос, jdbc

Делаю так:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO mydbcall1.Call0 (date,direction,operator,abonentTel,duration,coast1,coast2,corpPhone)" +
                " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
try {

    ps.setDate(1,  new java.sql.Date(call.date.getTime()) );
    ps.setString(2, call.direction);
    ps.setString(3, call.operator);
    ps.setString(4, call.abonentTel);
    ps.setInt(5, call.duration);
    ps.setDouble(6, call.coast1);
    ps.setDouble(7, call.coast2);
    ps.setString(8, call.corpPhone);
    ps.executeUpdate(); // for INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE

} finally {
    ps.close();
}
```

метод для 3000 объектов работает больше 1.5 минут.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Не создавайте `PreparedStatement` каждый раз заново. Преимущество `PreparedStatement` перед обычным `Statement` именно в том, что можно его заранее отправить на сервер БД для компиляции и переиспользовать повторно.
2. Отправляйте вставки пакетами (batch). Вероятно, вам придется подобрать оптимальный размер пакета.
3. Используйте явное управление транзакцией. По-умолчанию транзакция завершается на каждый запрос к БД (`autoCommit = true`).

Вот пример с применением этих трех рекомендаций (используется `try-with-resources`):

```
private static final String INSERT_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO mydbcall1.Call0(date,direction,operator,abonentTel,duration,coast1,coast2,corpPhone) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

// ....

try (
    Connection connection = database.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_STATEMENT);
) {
    int i = 0;
    connection.setAutoCommit(false)
    for (Call call : calls) {
        ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(call.date.getTime()) );
        ps.setString(2, call.direction);
        ps.setString(3, call.operator);
        ps.setString(4, call.abonentTel);
        ps.setInt(5, call.duration);
        ps.setDouble(6, call.coast1);
        ps.setDouble(7, call.coast2);
        ps.setString(8, call.corpPhone);
        // ...

        ps.addBatch();
        i++;

        if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == calls.size()) {
            ps.executeBatch(); // ограничиваем размер одного пакета тысячей вставок
        }
    }
    connection.commit();
} catch(SQLException e) { 
    connection.rollback();
}
```

Comment: Nofate огромное спасибо.С Batch все должно быть гораздо быстрее. Очень помогло!!

Comment: statement.executeBatch(); - не могу понять. Этот стейтмент откуда взялся ? он на объявлен?

Comment: @KirillN, поправил, там ps, конечно

Comment: я у себя уже юзаю с ps. СПС!